# Simple dynamic link library linker error on mac OSX

Tags: c++, xcode, juce

I compiled the dynamic link library named 'NewProject.dylib' from this source code.

```
//
//  source.hpp
//  NewProject - Dynamic Library
//
//

#ifndef source_hpp
#define source_hpp

#include <stdio.h>

int greatest_common_divisor(int x, int y) {
  int r, tmp;
  if(x < y){
    tmp = x;
    x = y;
    y = tmp;
  }

  r= x % y;
  while(r != 0){
    x = y;
    y = r;
    r = x % y;
  }
  return y;
}
#endif /* source_hpp */
```

then I made test.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

int greatest_common_divisor(int x,int y);
int main() {
    greatest_common_divisor(1,2);
    std::cout << "Hello Test!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

try to compie

g++ -o test test.cpp -L ./ -INewProject

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "greatest_common_divisor(int, int)", referenced from:
      _main in test-90ee6f.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I think this is because of importing library doesn't work properly.

However where should I fix???

Normally, the name should be lib***.so ??? I made dynamic library from `juce` framework.

Comment: As I see the ifdef guard is `source_hpp`, is it a header file? then it could be possible that there is no symbol `greatest_common_divisor` in your dylib file.

Comment: THank you , I maybe misunderstanding the framwork itself. I re-start from the scratch

Comment: I think it would be nice to check if the symbol is present in `NewProject.dylib` with `nm` command.

Comment: wow `nm` command also useful for my debug.